# How to represent a known function in pymc and then update it with new data?

Tags: pymc

I have the following function: `y = a + b X + c Z`

where, I know that `a = N(1 , 0.1)`; `b = N(5, .5)`; and `c = N(10, 1)` where `N(mu, sigma)` is a normal distribution. The data used to arrive at the coefficients are unavailable.

How can I model the existing function and update it with new data in PyMC when it becomes available?

```
with pm.Model() as func:
    a = pm.Normal("a", mu=1, sigma=0.1)
    b = pm.Normal("b", mu=5, sigma=0.5)
    c = pm.Normal("c", mu=10, sigma=1)
    y = a + X * b + Z * c                #X, Z is not known
```